# How to remove a margin when a div go to a new line?

Tags: css, margin

I have a container div with a fixed width : 160px

I can have multiple button inside this container and the addition of the widths can be superior to 160px. Each button have a margin-left set at 10px except the first button using css.

When buttons got to the new line i would like to remove the margin-left.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kukL6k3z/)

```
<div class="container">
    <button>Button #1</button>
    <button>Button #2</button>
    <button>Button #3</button>
    <button>Button #4</button>
    <button>Button #5</button>
    <button>Button #6</button>
    <button>Button #7</button>
    <button>Button #8</button>
</div>

    .container{
    width:160px;
    position:relative;

    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}

button:not(:first-child) { margin-left:10px;}
```

Thanks in advance for your precious help !

Comment: Why not use padding on the container div instead?

Comment: Not sure how you want to display, Are you want something like this. https://jsfiddle.net/kukL6k3z/2/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just update your CSS like this, add `tr` in css after  `:first-child`

```
button:not(:first-child tr) { margin-left:10px;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kukL6k3z/2/

So all buttons are left -aligned and two in one row.

Comment: Explain how does tr work. IMO the selector applies to all buttons including the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Change `margin` to `text-indent`, this will ensure only the first line is indented.

```
.container{
    text-indent:160px;
    position:relative;

    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/GarryPas/kukL6k3z/1/